# Почему Notification повторяются?

Tags: java, android

Мое приложение использует `AlarmManager` broadcast receiver, посылает  уведомления.
Все работает хорошо, но когда я запускаю уведомление в определенное время, оно появляется, а потом повторяется еще несколько раз(одно и тоже).

Я добавил в alarmservece `Integer i = 0;` и "Текст" + i++`

Если запустить несколько уведомлений, повторяется только первое.
Когда выскакивает проблемное второе уведомление вот лог.
Что это?

```
09-28 13:55:55.598  16489-16489/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-28 13:55:55.668  16489-16489/com.example.nes.app E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-28 13:55:55.668  16489-16489/com.example.nes.app D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
09-28 13:55:55.668  16489-16489/com.example.nes.app D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
09-28 13:55:55.668  16489-16489/com.example.nes.app D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
```

### receiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);

        context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

### alarmManager.class

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
    NotificationManager mManager;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    String eventCode = "EV_KEY";
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),onResume.class);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, getResources().getString(R.string.timeToSmoke), System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE ;
        notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        i++;

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.time), "Text"+String.valueOf(i), pendingNotificationIntent);
        Random r = new Random();
        int id = r.nextInt(10000 - 50) + 50;
         mManager.notify(id, notification);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

### как я вызываю Alarm Manager

```
void StartAlarm(int day, int hour, int minutes) {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Random r = new Random();
    int rcode = r.nextInt(10000 - 50) + 50;
    rcodeAlarm.add(String.valueOf(rcode));

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Time.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Time.this, rcode, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    timeAlarm.add(String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решено!  Не знаю почему это сработало, но оно сработало.
Просто убрал весь  код из AlarmManager service и вставил все в recever.
До сих пор не пойму зачем мне нужно было это переходящее звено.
Но вопрос все равно открыт! Почему так не работало?

Comment: скорее всего надо было в сервисе использовать stopself() после его выполнения.